# How to create xml of this structure in titanium using Ti.XML.DOMImplementation

Tags: xml, titanium

How to create xml of this structure in titanium using Ti.XML.DOMImplementation?

```
        <root>
        <first element name= "text here 1"/>
        <second element name= "text here 2"/>
        <third element name= "text here 2"/>
        </root>
```

Comment: What are you asking here? Are you talking about Alloy?

Comment: Josaih ,I mean how to create above xml structure using Titanium.XML or Ti.XML.DOMImplementation , not talking about Alloy.

Comment: You use those API's to parse / process XML, not generate it. To generate it, just output the above.

Comment: By "output the above", you mean generating string of the same structure,as I need to send this xml to server?

Comment: Yes. If you want to send this xml to the server, send a string.